# Why am i not able to get result as "true" in below code?

Tags: powershell

```
$my_courses = @("course1 # Learning Task Automations # New", "course2 # Advanced Scripting & tool making # New2", "course3 # AD Management using PowerShell /In progress # New3")

$my_courses.Contains("Task")
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `$my_courses` is an array of strings, so you should not use the **string** method `.Contains` on it as a whole.
You *can* use that for each array element separately, but then remember `.Contains` works Case-Sensitively which is probably not what you want:

If what you want is to test whether one of these courses contain the substring "task", and simply return either `$true` or `$false` then I suggest one of the following:

```
$my_courses = "course1 # Learning Task Automations # New", 
              "course2 # Advanced Scripting & tool making # New2", 
              "course3 # AD Management using PowerShell /In progress # New3"
```

1. use `-like` with wildcards and cast the result to Boolean. If no element contains "task", the result will be $false

```
[bool]($my_courses -like "*task*")
```

2. use `-match` and cast the result to Boolean

```
[bool]($my_courses -match "task")
```

If you want the word task to be a whole word, enclose it with `\b` word boundary metacharacters.
This will prevent receiving True on words like "Taskforce"

```
[bool]($my_courses -match "\btask\b")
```

3. use a `Where-Object` clause to filter the array of elements that contain "task", then again cast to Boolean

```
[bool]($my_courses | Where-Object { $_ -match 'task' })
```

4. use `[regex]::IsMatch()`

```
# (?i) makes it case-insensitive and the \b around it make it a whole word search
[regex]::IsMatch($my_courses, '(?i)\btask\b')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.contains` method looks for an exact match e.g.

```
$my_courses.contains("course1 # Learning Task Automations # New")
```

The method does not support wildcards - try using `-like`

```
$my_courses -like "*Task*"
```